# Array index out of range [swift]

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a set of Strings, which I split it out and save it into an Array, and try to loop it with api as a parameter, but it keep crash with error

> index out of range

why is it? Need help pls

[image: array]

Comment: Please paste code in text, no image

Comment: `for i in qrCodeArray.indices { }`

Comment: @LeoDabus then how do i save it all into an array again?

Answer (score 0):

Your `qrCodeArray` Array is empty also you need to `for loop` less one to the count of `qrCodeArray`. So change you for loop like this.

```
for i in 0..<qrCodeArray.count {

}
```

In your case `for i in 0...qrCoderArray.count {` it will execute for loop if your `qrCoderArray.count` is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You should learn about array basic ideas. This error shows becuse the item you request is not available in the array.

```
for i in 0...qrCoderArrau.count - 1 {

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are trying to access an element in array with an index greater than its size - 1.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid those errors (the last index of an array is `count-1`) use always

```
for qrCode in qrCodeArray { ...
```

rather than an index loop and even if you need the index use

```
for (index, qrCode) in qrCodeArray.enumerate() { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think best solution is **foreach** in these situations

```
for qr in qrCoderArray {
    ...
}
```